# XUnit CustomWebApplicationFactory with fluent validator and dependency injection

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit, fluentvalidation

I am writing some unit tests for my AspNetCore 2.2 MVC application. I want to use CustomWebApplicationFactory by XUnit to substitute my dbcontext for an inmemory one, with this standard code:

```
    public class TestWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                    .BuildServiceProvider();

            services.AddDbContext<IDemoDbContext, DemoDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
                options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
            });

            var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            using (var scope = provider.CreateScope())
            {
                var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var demoContext = (DemoDbContext)scopedServices.GetRequiredService<IDemoDbContext>();
                var logger = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<TestWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>>>();
                demoContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

                try
                {
                    var seeder = new DemoDbSeeder(demoContext);
                    seeder.SeedAllTables();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.LogError(ex, $"An error occurred seeding the test database. Error: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My tests keep failing at the FluentValidation validator that needs dbcontext to validate new values against the existing ones.

```
public class UpdateEntityCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<UpdateEntityCommand>
{
    private readonly IDemoDbContext _dbContext;
    public UpdateEntityCommandValidator(IDemoDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;

        RuleFor(j => j.Status).Must((j, status) => BeValidStatusTransition(j.RxJobId, status)).WithMessage("Invalid status transition.");
    }


    private bool BeValidStatusTransition(Guid entityId, string newStatus)
    {
        // Do validation against existing status in the database
    }
}
```

While the code works flawlessly with SQL server in StartUp and dbContext gets injected. When I run the test, DbSets in the context are empty. I debugged through and can tell that seeding works and I have entities after SeedAllTables. I can only assume the problem is with dependency injection. Could someone point me in the right direction on how this issue can be solved?

Comment: `options.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());` this will execute *once* per every service scope created. So if you seed the database in one scope, then accessing the database context in another scope will give you a new/empty database since that generated a new Guid.

Comment: @poke Mate, I cannot believe that actually worked. Thank you, you are a brilliant man!